# Bootstrap 4.0.0 fail W3C validation?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, w3c, w3c-validation

I'm encountering a problem with an application I'm making, which try to Minificate my whole `.css` files.

It seems that `bootstrap` is failing `W3C` validation, on both [normal](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmaxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com%2Fbootstrap%2F4.0.0%2Fcss%2Fbootstrap.css&profile=css3svg&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=it) and [.min](http://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator?uri=https%3A%2F%2Fmaxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com%2Fbootstrap%2F4.0.0%2Fcss%2Fbootstrap.min.css&profile=css3svg&usermedium=all&warning=1&vextwarning=&lang=it) version.

Any clues about this problem?

Comment: Maintainer of the W3C HTML Checker here. You can actually now use the HTML Checker to check CSS files too. Try https://validator.w3.org/nu/?doc=https%3A%2F%2Fmaxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com%2Fbootstrap%2F4.0.0%2Fcss%2Fbootstrap.css and you’ll find that you get no errors. That’s because the bootstrap stylesheets use CSS variables (CSS custom properties), which the W3C CSS checker doesn’t yet recognize, and that’s what’s causing the errors you’re seeing. But the HTML Checker does recognize CSS variables, and that’s why it reports no errors for that bootstrap stylesheet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Bootstrap's documentation [explains the issue](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/browsers-devices/#validators). They are using some "hacks" as workarounds for bugs of certain browsers, and also new CSS features that may not have support in validators yet.

Apart from these, the rest of their CSS is valid.

> In order to provide the best possible experience to old and buggy
>   browsers, **Bootstrap uses CSS browser hacks** in several places to target
>   special CSS to certain browser versions in order to work around bugs
>   in the browsers themselves. These hacks understandably **cause CSS
>   validators to complain** that they are invalid. In a couple places, we
>   **also use bleeding-edge CSS features** that aren’t yet fully
>   standardized, but these are used purely for progressive enhancement.
>
> These validation warnings don’t matter in practice since **the non-hacky
>   portion of our CSS does fully validate** and the hacky portions don’t
>   interfere with the proper functioning of the non-hacky portion, hence
>   why we deliberately ignore these particular warnings.